# Running PHP short tag on localhost Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, bitnami

Got Wordpress website with PHP short tags `<?`, tried Bitnami, Laragon, both doesn't support it. I have found that I need to change php.init file with `short_open_tag = On`, but I can't find it inside Bitnami installed folder. Where I suppose to look for it?

Comment: The usage of short open tags is deprecated. Don't rely on that, rather **always** use proper open tags

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, you can find the php.ini file inside the /opt/bitnami/php folder. You can find more information about the directory structure [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/faq/get-started/understand-directory-structure/)

Comment: Thank you, my mistake that I was looking "php.init" and not "php.ini"